# Erro ao consultar grande quantidade de dados no Entity framework,

Tags: c#, entity-framework, desempenho

Estou montando um relatório, e nele existe a opção de consultar por período de datas. Quando faço a consulta com o intervalo de 30 ou 60 dias, consigo obter os dados, onde agrupo e retorno.

Porém, ao aumentar o período de consulta, o mesmo método retorna o erro de: *500 (Internal Server Error)*. Pesquisando, notei que em alguns casos o entity framework, encerra a consulta por causa do *time out* ou pela quantidade de dados a ser processados.

Obs: Essa mesma consulta que fiz pelo entity, realizei diretamente no sql server, passando os parâmetros, para checar se realmente retornaria dados(e retornou como o esperado).

```
public IQueryable ObterNotaSimplificada(DateTime compInicial, DateTime compFinal,
        PorteContribuinte? codigoPorte, string query, int? itemServico, bool? simplesNacional)
    {
        var res = this.Servicos
            .Include(x => x.Prestador)
            .Where(a => (a.Competencia >= compInicial && a.Competencia <= compFinal) &&
                        (codigoPorte == null || a.Prestador.Porte.Value == codigoPorte) &&
                        (simplesNacional == null || a.Prestador.IsSimplesNacional == simplesNacional) &&
                        (itemServico == null || a.ItemListaServico.Id == itemServico) &&
                        ((query == null || a.Prestador.RazaoSocial.Contains(query))
                         || (a.Prestador.CpfCnpj.Contains(query))))
            .Where(a => a.DataCancelamento == null)
            .GroupBy(a => a.Prestador.CpfCnpj)
            .Select(g => new
            {
                CNPJ = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.CpfCnpj),
                Competencia = g.Select(x => x.Competencia),
                RazaoSocial = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.RazaoSocial),
                SimplesNacional = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.IsSimplesNacional),
                Porte = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.Porte),
                DescricaoPorte = g.Select(x => x.Prestador.Porte.ToString()),
                QtdNotasEmitidas = g.Count(),
                BaseDeCalculo = g.Select(x => x.BaseCalculo),
                ValorDeducoes = g.Select(x => x.ValorDeducoes),
                ValorServicos = g.Select(x => x.ValorServicos),
                ValorIss = g.Select(x => x.ValorInss),
                TotalBaseDeCalculo = g.Sum(x => x.BaseCalculo),
                TotalValorDeducoes = g.Sum(x => x.ValorDeducoes),
                TotalValorServicos = g.Sum(x => x.ValorServicos),
                TotalValorIss = g.Sum(x => x.ValorIss),
                IssRetido = g.Select(x => x.IssRetido > decimal.Zero),
                ItemDeServico = g.Select(x => x.ItemListaServico.Descricao),
                CodItemServico = g.Select(x => x.ItemListaServico.Codigo)
            });
        return  res;
    }
```

Comment: tem que ver o que é `ItemListaServico` por exemplo... se estiver com lazy dentro de cada registro ele vai executar outro select pra buscar esse objeto... tira o count também, se estiver contando uma coleção dentro de cada objeto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que você está retornando muitos dados, utiliza funções de agrupamento (Group By, Sum) e isso exige muito do entity framework. Quando se trabalha com muitos dados é recomendado utilizar a própria query SQL, pelo fato da perfomance ser melhor.

Tente utilizar esse exemplo, mas adaptando para sua query:

```
var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("SELECT COLUNAS FROM NOMETABELA").ToArray();
```

Caso a performance continue ruim, recomendo que crie índices para sua base de dados.